# Much better results when standardizing features to train LSTMs

Tags: python, lstm, accuracy, keras

I have a data set of time series. Each time series represents trajectories of the same path taken. So, the time series captures acceleration in $x$, $y$ and $z$ direction, respectively for the rotation. In addition to that environmental properties are collected such as temperature, humidity, air pressure, light spectrum values, magnetic field and so on. I am training the following LSTM to recognise its current position on the path (column for `Positions` (y):

```
model_2_0 = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.LSTM(64, activation="relu", return_sequences = True, input_shape= (win_length, num_features)),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.LSTM(64, activation="relu", return_sequences=True),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.LSTM(64, activation="relu"),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(23, activation="softmax")                  
], name=model_name)

# Save summary


# Compile model
model_2_0.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
#            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00003),
            metrics=["accuracy"]) 
history_2_0 = model_2_0.fit(X_train, 
                        y_train, 
                        epochs=25, 
                        validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), 
                        #batch_size=1024, 
                        batch_size=200,
                        verbose=1)
```

Now, if I standardize the features, the accuracy is much better so that the val accuracy in the first epoch is 78% (val loss 0.6) and in the last 90.8% (val loss 0.47) with a test accuracy of 90.7% (loss 0.47).
If I normalize the timeseries (min max normalization), the increase of the val accuracy in the first epochs is  not that great compared to standardization.

So, I am not quite sure whether there is a problem with standardizing the data in my context and whether I train my net correctly. So, should I normalize or standardize the data given the context?

Comment: if you standardize your data first and then run the code above after, you are essentially giving away to the algorithm the range of variation of the unseen data. Not surprised this would radically improve the test performance.

Comment: @user603 So, normalizing before training would be an option in this case instead of standardizing?

Comment: I think the point being made by @user603 is that you should standardise or normalise based on the training data alone, and not include the test data at that stage.  This reflects the testing paradigm: you are building a model which you will test on future as-yet unknown information

Comment: @Henry Yes I am doing that right now. But after training the model, to evaluate the model correctly I have to also use the same preprocessing for the testing data, right?

Comment: @Invader That is correct: you remember the rescaling and relocation you did to the training data and apply that to the test data